# OR/AND condition for complex criteria with remote objects

Tags: remote-objects

How to join  complex condition with OR in where clause of remote objects like here:

```
{ 
where: 
    { 
    or: 
        [
        {IsClosed: {eq: false}, Status: {ed: 'Open'}},
        {Status: {ed: 'Open'}}]
    }
}
```

This doesn't work

Comment: Not a complete answer. But at [Spring 14 - What clauses are permitted when querying SObjects using Visualforce Remote Objects?](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000193198&language=en_US) it says: "In Spring 14, remoteObject queries support the following clauses:

WHERE
LIMIT
OFFSE
eq (equal)
less than (<)
greater than (>)
LIKE
AND
OR"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you want records where:

- it `is not closed` and the `Status is 'Open'`
- or the `Status is 'Open'`

Firstly, assuming I've got your logic correct, you don't need the `is not closed` check in the first part of the clause. `(A and B) or B` is logically equivalent to just `B`. This is from boolean algebra. See [the second Absorption law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Monotone_laws).

Still, in terms of syntax for combining `and` and `or`, I think you are missing an `and`. Try:

```
{ 
where: 
    { 
    or: 
        {
            and:
                {
                IsClosed: {eq: false},
                Status: {ed: 'Open'}
                },
            {Status: {ed: 'Open'}}
        }
    }
}
```

See also: [Format and Options for Remote Objects Query Criteria](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_remote_objects_using_retrieve_query_object.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Someone may find this useful. Here's an example of some success I had with handling a date range:

```
                {
                    'where': {
                        'and': {
                            'CreatedDate': { 'gte': account_created_from_date },
                            'and': {
                                'CreatedDate': { 'lte': account_created_to_date },
                                'Id': { 'gt': '' }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```