# ORs and ANDs in the retrieve function of Visualforce Remote Objects

Tags: visualforce, javascript, query, javascript-remoting, remote-objects

**Related**: [OR/AND condition for complex criteria with remote objects](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42090/or-and-condition-for-complex-criteria-with-remote-objects)

#### Background

The `retrieve` query format allows the use of `or` and `and` clauses to create complex queries.  [The relevant documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_js_remoting.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fpages_js_remoting.htm|SkinName=webhelp) is at the end of this post.

But, JS maps only allows one value per key.

#### Question

How do I specify an `or` of one field's value?  For instance, how do I build a query for an account where (`BillingState` is any of (`Hawaii`, `Alaska`, or `California`)) `and` (`Name` is like `% Assoc%`)?

The obvious answer (below) does not work, because JS engines will simply use the last value for `BillingState` (`{ eq: 'California'}`):

```
where: {
  or: {
    BillingState: { eq: 'Hawaii' },
    BillingState: { eq: 'Alaska' },
    BillingState: { eq: 'California' }
  }, 
  Name: { like: '% Assoc%' }
}
```

#### Official Documentation

Also see [salesforce docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#CSHID=pages_js_remoting.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fpages_js_remoting.htm|SkinName=webhelp).

> `where` conditions enable you to filter the results of a retrieve operation, much the same way that a `WHERE` condition in a SOQL query does. The operators that are available for where conditions are:
>
> ```
> eq: equals
> ne: not equals
> lt: less than
> lte: less than or equals
> gt: greater than
> gte: greater than or equals
> like: string matching. As with SOQL, use “%” as a wildcard character.
> and: logical AND, used for combining conditions
> or—logical OR, used for combining conditions
> ```
>
> Within the where object, add field name and condition pairs to create complex criteria. Multiple conditions by default are treated as AND conditions. You can use `and` and `or` to create other criteria conditions. For example:
>
> ```
> {
>   where: {
>     or: {
>       FirstName: { like: "M%" },
>       Phone: { like: '(415)%' }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: This very basic use case (as it stands) is no longer a problem with the quiet release of `in` and `nin` in the API.  However, there may still be more complex cases that require the hack below.

Comment: An example of a more complex case still not handled well is `or: { Name: { like: x }, Name: { like: y } }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**OPTION 1:** Nested logical constructions to prevent the clash of identifiers

```
where: {
  or: {
    BillingState: { eq: 'Hawaii' },
    or: {
      BillingState: { eq: 'Alaska' },
      or: {...},
    },    
  }, 
  Name: { like: '% Assoc%' }
}
```

Caution: it seems to be important, that all ors and ands have at least two nodes. So if necessary, you have to add fake-conditions which evaluate neutrally to your needs.

---

**OPTION 2:** Add the Model fields twice *(not verified)*

```
<apex:remoteObjects jsNamespace="RemoteObjectModel">
   <apex:remoteObjectModel name="Account" >
      <apex:remoteObjectField name="BillingState" jsShorthand="State1"/>
      <apex:remoteObjectField name="BillingState" jsShorthand="State2"/>
   </apex:remoteObjectModel>
</apex:remoteObjects>
```

Comment: brilliant (and really annoying)!  Let me see if that works!

Comment: Nope - `Invalid criteria specified for retrieval. ValidationError [code=11, message=Data does not match any schemas from &quot;oneOf&quot;, path=/where, schemaKey=null]`

Comment: It looks like you can't nest an `or` in an `or`

Comment: no, looks like it gets converted pretty early on in the process

Comment: hm.  It now looks like your first suggestion worked

Comment: The important bit is that all `or`s and `and`s need at least two nodes.  To fill in your `...`, I did: `and: { Name: {like: '%'}, BillingState: {eq: 'California'} }`

Comment: that should be no problem - you can always create a fake-argument with a neutral impact, like or: {always-false, condition1}