# Remote Object Query not respecting multiple criteria on single field

Tags: visualforce, json, remote-objects

I'm trying to utilize Remote Objects in order to query a Custom Object. Part of my criteria involves getting all records during a particular date range off of a single field.

```
{
    where:
    {
        Custom_Date_Time__c: {gte: new Date('2014-1-1')},
        Custom_Date_Time__c: {lte: new Date('2016-1-1')}
    },
    limit: 100
}
```

My query returns records but only the second listed `Custom_Date_Time__c` criteria is respected. So as it is written now it will return all records with `Custom_Date_Time__c` earlier than January 1st, 2016.  If I switch the the lines to

```
{
    where:
    {
        Custom_Date_Time__c: {lte: new Date('2016-1-1')},
        Custom_Date_Time__c: {gte: new Date('2014-1-1')}
    },
    limit: 100
}
```

then I will get all records with `Custom_Date_Time__c` after January 1st, 2014.

I found this [SE Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45173/ors-and-ands-in-the-retrieve-function-of-visualforce-remote-objects) asking about combining `and:` and `or:` that might suggest the solution to my problem is formatting my JSON object in a certain manner, but my attempts to do so have all resulted in errors.

Comment: Are you certain you get dates lt 2014-1-1 in the first case and gt 2016-1-1 in the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the link you sent in your question is your answer unfortunately - as far as I know - so in your case you need to make up another criteria and use AND:

```
var options = {
  where: {
    and: {
      Custom_Date_Time__c: {lte: new Date('2016-1-1')},
      and: {
       Custom_Date_Time__c: {gte: new Date('2014-1-1')},
       Id: {ne: '123'}
      }
    }
  },
  limit: 100
```

}

Hope this helps!

- Florian

If you are using AngularJS with RemoteObjects have a look at [ngRemote](https://github.com/florianhoehn/ngRemote)

Comment: I've not been using Angular but I do intend to look into it in the near future.  I'll also take a look at ngRemote.  Thanks.