# Visualforce Remote Object Query 'where-like' Condition using a List of String

Tags: visualforce, remote-objects

Is it possible to query a 'where like' list of string with remote object? That is possible in Apex soql:

```
Set<String> LikeNameSet= new set<String>();
LikeNameSet.add('%test1%');
LikeNameSet.add('%test2%');
List <Contact> conList =  [select id, email from Contact where email like:LikeNameSet];
```

However I tried the analogy in vain using remote object:

```
<apex:remoteObjects >
    <apex:remoteObjectModel name="Contact" jsShorthand="conRemoteObj" fields="Id, Email"/>       
</apex:remoteObjects> 
<script> 
    ...
    var conObj = new SObjectModel.conRemoteObj();
    let likeEmailList = ['%test1','%test2%'];
    let criteria = {
        where: {     
            Email: {like: likeEmailList }     
        } 
    };                               

    conObj.retrieve(criteria,callback);   

    function callback(){    
        //do something here...    
    }      
    ...    
</script>
```

the code above results in javascript alert error like:

```
> Error in Callback Contact Invalid criteria specified for
> retrieval. ValidationError [code=11, message=Data does not match any
> schemas from &quot;oneOf&quot;, path=/where, schemaKey=null]
```

I cannot find anything about this where-like syntax in documentation:

> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects_using_retrieve_query_object.htm

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nishad, the following nested syntax works for me according to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects_using_retrieve_query_object.htm.

```
let criteria = {
    where: {
        Id: {in: ids},
        or:{
            Email: {like: '%test1%'},
            or:{
                and:{
                    firstname: {eq: 'dummy'},
                    lastname: {eq: 'dummy'},
                },
                Email: {like: '%test2%'} 
            }                                      
        }
    } 
};
```

Please vote for improvement on salesforce idea exchange

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000LsEbQAK

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add 'in' after the 'like' condition, try like this

instead of

```
   where: {     
                Email: {like: likeEmailList }     
          }
```

try like this

```
   where: {     
                    Email: {like:{ in: likeEmailList} }     
              }
```

if you are still facing any issue, the below method should work:

```
where: 
    { 
    or: 
        {
        Email: { like: "%test1" }, 
        Email: { like: '%test2%' }
        }
    }
```

Please check the below link to get more details of VF remote objects: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_remote_objects_using_retrieve_query_object.htm

Comment: thy for your suggestions. Sadly none of them works. Especially the second one, the official documentation is very misleading. Since Javascript does not understand the same field applied multiple times in or:{...}. The code above will lead to the same error as I posted. Check here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45173/ors-and-ands-in-the-retrieve-function-of-visualforce-remote-objects

Comment: Okay, Have u tried like this : where: 
    { 
    or: 
        {
        Email: { like: "%test1" },
        or:{  
        Email: { like: '%test2%' }
        },
    },
} Please let me know if this works